# Does mysql require two users in the users table for local and remote access?

Tags: mysql, permissions

I noticed in our databases that there are always two copies of every user, one with "From Host" set to % and the other with the "From Host" set to localhost. Is that necessary? It seems like it can only cause confusion to have a different set of permissions for a user depending on where it's coming from.

It also seems odd that % wouldn't match localhost.

Answer (score 0):

`From Host@%` would allow access from all locations.  `From Host@localhost` would only allow access from localhost.

Just check this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connection-access.html

Comment: That's what I would expect, but I think that if I remove user@localhost and have only user@% I'm not able to connect from the localhost.